# A simple spreadsheet sorting

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

In a Google Spreadsheet I have different groups of cells in one column to auto-sort. All cells in this column have same pattern of data, all datum have it's own cell and it's needed to be sorted into six or seven rows.

Example
[image]

There is no need to change data in any way, just to sort it.

I have a solution for small range using hardware macros, under 500 cells (and it was basically a legwork done by programmed keyboard), but now I face data ten time the size.

Can It be done?

Comment: So, in short, you want to sort a column into different columns according to the scheme you presented?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the problem. Any ides?

Answer (score 1):

The formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A:A, "select A where A contains '1.'"))
```

entered in C2, would fill C2, D2, E2 with 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, as in your example. You can also include a formula within the query so it's applicable to every row in your example:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A:A, "select A where A contains '"&ROW()-1&".'"))
```